# Optional Gradle properties

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a Gradle build file where one of the the tasks is to login into docker. In this task I want that the user/CI provides the parameter docker_username, docker_password and docker_email.

```
task loginDockerHub(group: "Docker",  type:Exec) {        
    executable "docker"
    args "login","-u", docker_username, "-p", docker_password, "-e", docker_email
}
```

Executing `gradle loginDockerHub -Pdocker_username=vad1mo ...` all is working as expected.

But when I execute for example `gradle build` I get the error:

> Could not find property 'docker_username' on task ':loginDockerHub'.

I would expect this error on executing `gradle loginDockerHub` without providing the  -P parameter, but not on other tasks that don't access docker_username/password parameters.

How can I have optional parameters for my `loginDockerHub` task in Gradle that don't make the parameter mandatory for any other task.

Comment: Remember that task *configuration* is always evaluated, regardless of whether the individual tasks are actually *executed*.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can check if the property exists and if not return a default.

```
args "login", "-u", project.hasProperty("docker_username") ? docker_username : ""
```

**Update:** Starting with Gradle 2.13 you can simplify this somewhat.

```
args "login", "-u", project.findProperty("docker_username") ?: ""
```

Comment: yes, same error. @oliver mentioned configuration phase. I guess this is the clue

Comment: @Oliver is correct, these properties are being evaluated during configurations, which is why you need to conditionally evaluate them if they are not always defined. The example above should work (you'll of course need to do that for all the properties). Another solutions is to define defaults in a *gradle.properties* file. Properties defined via the CLI will override these.

Comment: The code sample I posted does exactly that. The ternary statement only evaluates the property `docker_username` if it exists, otherwise the alternate value (in this case a string literal) is evaluated.

Comment: Important thing are the quotes around the key hasProperty("docker_username") I forgot that.

Answer (score 5):

I was not able to find a solution to the problem. [This description](http://www.practicalgradle.org/blog/category/tasks/) had a hint about about declaring  actions within a task. Putting the shell exec into the action task has the behavior I was expecting, because actions are evaluated when the task executes.

```
task loginDockerHub(group: "Docker",  type:Exec) {
    doFirst{
        executable "docker"
        args "login","-u", docker_username, "-p", docker_password, "-e", docker_email
    }
}
```

Executing the `loginDockerHub` without providing the `docker_*` parameters will yelled an error. Executing any other task will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this and didn't want my build to fail with an error.  I solved it by doing this:

```
ext.shouldLoginDockerHub = project.hasProperty("docker_username");

task loginDockerHub(group: "Docker") {
    doLast{
        if(shouldLoginDockerHub) {
            exec {
                executable "docker"
                args "login","-u", docker_username, "-p", docker_password, "-e", docker_email
            }
        } else {
            println "Not logging in to docker hub because docker_username was not provided.";
        }
    }
 }
```

You could expand the first line to look for docker_password, docker_email, etc.